# ng-repeat with includes: best performant way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I am facing a performance issue with Angular (Ionic), and I'd like to know which would be the most performant way to solve this problem.

I get a list of objects from a service that I have to show in my app:

```
  $scope.objectList = [
    {
       id: 123456,
       name: "abcdefg",
       state: [1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8...],
       ....
    },
    ....
  ];
```

The list won't never have more than 20-25 objects.

The problem is that the elements in the list, although they are of the same type, they have to be shown in a quite different way. I have a different template for each posible state an object can be in.

I am using ng-repeat this way to show the list. The list won't change so I can use one way binding.

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in ::objectList track by obj.id">
   ....    
</div>
```

Inside this ng-repeat I have to include the presentation template of each object, which changes depending on the object state.

I have tried different solutions but don'f find one that improves substantialy the rendering performance.

For example, I've tried this but I'm not sure that binding a function to ng-include is very performant.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in ::objects track by obj.id">
    <div ng-include="getTemplateToInclude(obj)"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getTemplateToInclude = function(obj){
    if(obj.state === 1){
        return "tmpls/template-a.html";
    }else if(obj.state === 2){
        return "tmpls/template-b.html";
    }
    ....
};
```

Any suggestion of how to deal with this problem? Whicch would be the best way to include this different templates in the same list?

Do I have to use the one way binding notation(::) in the included templates or it's enough with the one used in the ng-repeat?

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you actually testing the performance?  Also how big are these *item renderers* for each item?  Are we talking a few nested divs w. little in the way of binding or are they rather complex DOM structures w. nested directives and forms and such?

Comment: The nested divs are the detail views of each object that contain an image and some(5 to 8) fields (title,description,date...) as well as a couple of buttons. The DOM is not as simple as i'd like to, the title is absolute positioned over the image with a background gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the one-way binding template syntax (::) so I won't speak to that.  But based on your comments and original question, I think the best approach would be something along these lines:

- create a single *item renderer* template that will process your repeater items
- continue to use `track by` syntax in your repeater in order to *recycle* the item renderers
- based on the item's *type*, use a combination of `ng-show` & `ng-hide` to display the correct children nested in your template.

  ```
  <!-- item renderer template.html -->
  <div>
     <div ng-show="item.type == 'foo'"></div> 
     <div ng-show="item.type == 'bar'"></div> 
     <div ng-show="item.type == 'baz'"></div>
  </div>
  ```

Creating a single template combined with `track by` in the repeater will reuse the DOM elements, negating the need to pull them from the DOM and then insert new ones.

Using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` vs. `ng-if` is based on the same idea as above.  You are toggling the visibility of the DOM elements rather than destroying/creating them.

The reason I argue for this is that in nearly all performance-related tweaking, reusing or *recycling* objects are usually faster than destroying and then recreating new objects.  This is certainly true of Javascript, and while I've yet to test that theory in DOM manipulation, I would bet it too is true.  I'm making an educated guess but since you are using the Ionic framework, this should benefit mobile performance as well,

Just keep in mind, given the various permutations of what you could be showing and the number of rows of data, you might only see marginal performance gains.  Depending on the number of bindings inside your template, you might reach a point where the performance penalty for Angular's digest cycle to complete is the same as the performance gains from recycling your DOM elements.